# HP Compaq 8000 Error 1802: Processor Not Supported

Tags: cpu, motherboard, bios, compaq-desktop-computer

I have an HP Compaq 8000 Elite Ultra Slim PC that I use as a server. Because it has an LGA775 core 2 duo, I bought a core 2 quad with the same socket (I don't know the exact model # of the CPU but it is a 2.5ghz quad core). Upon installation of the new hardware, my computer gave me a beep and a screen saying: "1802-Processor not supported The system board does not support this processor". Along with my computer information and menu options. I have updated my BIOS twice, my CPU microcode, and my Intel Management Engine firmware , but to no avail. Why is this problem still occouring? Is the CPU simply incompatible with my motherboard?

Comment: There is more to CPU compatibility than just using the same socket. OEM computers tend to be quite restrictive in such matters.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Illustrated Parts and Service Map](http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c01944844) the only C2Q CPUs that can be used with it are the Q8400S, the Q9505S, and the Q9550S, none of which is a 2.5GHz part.

Answer (score -1):

Using the 2.4 GHz 4 Core 8 MB cache CPU, my HP Compaq 8000 Elite Ultra Slim Desktop didn't want to work with this CPU: 2.83 GHz 12 Mb cache 4 core. **After some research i do believe that only CPU with 65 Watts tdp can work in this PC**, however i put to work the Q6600 here, only low power CPU whit 65 Watts tdp

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Check out these tips about how to write a good answer: https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: I think Julio was pointing out from his experience only a 65W CPU works in this PC model. He must assumed the poster was using a CPU requiring more power. He SHOULD link to the 'research' he did. It seems english may not be his first language so I tried to edit it to clean it up some

Comment: Well, about the 65 Watt limit, i figure out myself after trying 2.83 GHZ CPU 4 core 12 MB cache, and  also a 2.66 GHZ CPU 4 core, and analyzing the list of CPU and checking the TDP of each one, however, i do not now why, i got the 2.4 GHZ CPU 4 core 8 MB cache working, and that CPU have the TDP higher than 65 Watt